# How to confirm Webhook POST is being received in Coldfusion

Tags: json, coldfusion, webhooks, coldfusion-10

To be clear upfront, I'm not a professional - just trying to get a task done and I have minimal expertise. What I thought would be easy is apparently not so. I've dealt with APIs and XML but it's always been me initiating. This is apparently different.

**Goal:**

Receive HTTP POST Webhook data (JSON) from my Wordpress/Woocommerce website.

**Problem:**

The Webhook is working and being received perfectly by RequestBin.The JSON string is being sent over HTTP. But I'm not even sure the request is being heard by my CF Template.  When I try to write the received data into a session variable so I can at least see it, nothing is there?!?! How do I find out if my code being triggered?

First line of code in my CF Template:

```
<cfset HTTPRequestData = deserializeJSON(ToString(getHTTPRequestData().content))>
```

---

Example from RequestBin of data being sent:

```
{
    "id": 259609,
    "parent_id": 0,
    "number": "CW-104-270219",
    "order_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "created_via": "checkout",
    "version": "3.5.5",
    "status": "completed",
    "currency": "USD",
    "date_created": "2019-02-27T15:11:58",
    "date_created_gmt": "2019-02-27T20:11:58",
    "date_modified": "2019-02-27T15:11:59",
    "date_modified_gmt": "2019-02-27T20:11:59",
    "discount_total": "0.00",
    "discount_tax": "0.00",
    "shipping_total": "0.00",
    "shipping_tax": "0.00",
    "cart_tax": "0.00",
    "total": "9.68",
    "total_tax": "0.00",
    "prices_include_tax": false,
    "customer_id": 2,
    "customer_ip_address": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "customer_user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36",
    "customer_note": "",
    "billing": {
        "first_name": "Valerie",
        "last_name": "Criswell",
        "company": "",
        "address_1": "",
        "address_2": "",
        "city": "",
        "state": "",
        "postcode": "",
        "country": "",
        "email": "xxxxxxxxxx",
        "phone": ""
    },
    "shipping": {
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "company": "",
        "address_1": "",
        "address_2": "",
        "city": "",
        "state": "",
        "postcode": "",
        "country": ""
    },
    "payment_method": "authorize_net_aim",
    "payment_method_title": "Credit Card",
    "transaction_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "date_paid": "2019-02-27T15:11:59",
    "date_paid_gmt": "2019-02-27T20:11:59",
    "date_completed": "2019-02-27T15:11:59",
    "date_completed_gmt": "2019-02-27T20:11:59",
    "cart_hash": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "meta_data": [
        {
            "id": 8785641,
            "key": "_wcson_order_number",
            "value": "CWD-259609-022719-108"
        },
        {
            "id": 8785642,
            "key": "_order_number",
            "value": "104"
        },
        {
            "id": 8785643,
            "key": "_order_number_formatted",
            "value": "CW-104-270219"
        },
        {
            "id": 8785644,
            "key": "_order_number_meta",
            "value": {
                "prefix": "CW-",
                "suffix": "-{DD}{MM}{YY}",
                "length": "2"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 8785645,
            "key": "_wc_authorize_net_aim_retry_count",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": 8785646,
            "key": "_wc_authorize_net_aim_trans_id",
            "value": "xxxxxxxx"
        },
        {
            "id": 8785647,
            "key": "_wc_authorize_net_aim_trans_date",
            "value": "2019-02-27 15:11:59"
        },
        {
            "id": 8785648,
            "key": "_wc_authorize_net_aim_environment",
            "value": "production"
        },
        {
            "id": 8785649,
            "key": "_wc_authorize_net_aim_account_four",
            "value": "xxxxxxxx"
        },
        {
            "id": 8785650,
            "key": "_wc_authorize_net_aim_authorization_amount",
            "value": "xxxxxxx"
        },
        {
            "id": 8785651,
            "key": "_wc_authorize_net_aim_authorization_code",
            "value": "xxxxxxx"
        },
        {
            "id": 8785652,
            "key": "_wc_authorize_net_aim_charge_captured",
            "value": "yes"
        },
        {
            "id": 8785653,
            "key": "_wc_authorize_net_aim_card_expiry_date",
            "value": "21-08"
        },
        {
            "id": 8785654,
            "key": "_wc_authorize_net_aim_card_type",
            "value": "mastercard"
        },
        {
            "id": 8785659,
            "key": "_pip_invoice_number",
            "value": "CW-104-270219"
        },
        {
            "id": 8785660,
            "key": "_wc_pip_invoice_email_count",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 8785661,
            "key": "_wc_pip_packing_list_email_count",
            "value": "1"
        }
    ],
    "line_items": [
        {
            "id": 17,
            "name": "I Give Myself Away -   MP3 Download - 30 Day Access",
            "product_id": 192127,
            "variation_id": 192128,
            "quantity": 1,
            "tax_class": "",
            "subtotal": "9.68",
            "subtotal_tax": "0.00",
            "total": "9.68",
            "total_tax": "0.00",
            "taxes": [],
            "meta_data": [
                {
                    "id": 182,
                    "key": "pa_format",
                    "value": "download-30-day"
                }
            ],
            "sku": "131599-DL30DAY",
            "price": 9.68
        }
    ],
    "tax_lines": [],
    "shipping_lines": [],
    "fee_lines": [],
    "coupon_lines": [],
    "refunds": []
}
```

Comment: Your question is very broad and is likely to be closed. I recommend looking into how `<cfhttp>` works and ask a new question based on what you find there.

Comment: This question is difficult to answer because it’s way too broad. I suggest you narrow it down to the first problem... how do you know your webhook is being called and what data is being sent to it. You also mention that you’re not a professional, but you’re trying to accomplish something that is in the realm of professional work, so how would we even know what to suggest?

Comment: Leaving aside the question of professional work, if you do attempt this, start simply.  While your idea of inspecting getHTTPRequestData() is a good one, don't add any additional function calls just yet or throw in session variables. Keep any troubleshooting code as simple as possible, because the more things you throw into the mix, the greater the chance of problems.  Since it's an asynchronous request, you won't know if an error occurred unless you check the CF logs. Start with what Adrian suggested - dump the raw request data to a file on the server. Then go from there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the stated goal:

> Receive HTTP POST Webhook data from my Wordpress/Woocommerce website.

Can your Wordpress site hit the intended URL on your ColdFusion site? If so, can you record / dump the HTTP POST request to a file?

```
<cfdump var="#form#" format="html" output="/full/path/to/file">
```

This will tell you if you're even receiving the request correctly.

Comment: You should also dump getHTTPRequestData() to a file in case the data is POST'd to the body (i.e. FORM is empty).

Comment: SCORE on both. The webhook is being received, and I can see the data.I think the only other pieces of information I need are, what exactly am I looking at? Is this a coldfusion STRUCTURE or ARRAY? And how can I loop over the line_items (see output code above)? Extremely thankful for the kind assistance.

Comment: Couple things about SO. It is not used for threaded conversations. Once you solve a problem. You should try to work on the next one. There are lots of articles on how to loop over data in ColdFusion. Just Google ColdFusion Tutorial and you should be able to find stuff.